# Jenkins pipeline uses different java version from the one specified in the script

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My spring boot application uses java 11 but my jenkins server has java 8 installed. Hence I added a new JDK in the global tool configuration. I specified [this](https://github.com/adoptium/temurin11-binaries/releases/download/jdk-11.0.13%2B8/OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_11.0.13_8.tar.gz) download URL to be extracted in the JDK configuration. I specified a label (node name) and a sub directory too. My configuration looks like this.
[image]

I specified the JDK name in my pipeline script as shown below but when I do `java -version` from the pipeline script I still get the result as jdk 8. The `JAVA_HOME` path shows up correctly. Could someone guide me on what could be the issue?

Thanks

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        jdk 'AdoptOpenJDK11'
        maven 'Maven_3_8_1'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo $JAVA_HOME$'
                sh 'java -version'
                sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Jenkins logs are as below

```
+ echo /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/AdoptOpenJDK11/jdk11_13$
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/AdoptOpenJDK11/jdk11_13$
[Pipeline] sh
+ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
[Pipeline] sh
+ mvn -B -DskipTests clean package
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around the problem by specifying a docker image for the 'Build' stage

```
        stage('Build') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'maven:3.8.1-adoptopenjdk-11'
                    args '-u root -v /root/.m2:/root/.m2 -v "$pwd":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app'
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package'
            }
        }
```